# Severe thrombocytopenia as an indicator of the septic process

Tags: thrombocytopenia

I consider a case when Klebsiella pneumoniae was detected in the patient's blood and a septic process began to develop. During the week, the number of platelets in the blood dropped from 80.000 to 11.000/µl.

I have a few questions about this case:

1. The following blood test indicates this:

   PLT (microscopy): 0 (57)

I don't understand why two numbers are used here: 0 and 57. What is the actual number of platelets?
Can we assume that there are no platelets at all?

2. What negative consequences can such thrombocytopenia cause in sepsis?
   The patient has not had any bleeding before. Can they appear? What risk scores can be used?
3. I am also interested in the rate of development of thrombocytopenia in sepsis, as well as the rate of platelet recovery in the blood.
   Are there any statistical data and descriptions of such clinical cases?

Comment: Please decide what is most important for you to know about, and focus your question on that (there are too many questions here.) Also, some evidence of research is expected of users posting a question on this site. Without providing this, it's unlikely your question will remain open for long. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close for the reason given, but even if you narrow it to one question as suggested, you still need to provide some evidence of prior research. Have you attempted to answer the question yourself? If so, what did you find, and if nothing, what did you search for?